# How to log unhandled exceptions (with request ID) in AWS Lambda using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda provides built-in logging configuration as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html#python-logging-lib) so that log records include timestamp and request ID. Request ID is a UUID for a particular invocation of a Lambda function, so it's important to include it in each log record because it allows the user to query for all log records with a given request ID (using CloudWatch Logs Insights), which allows for retrieving log records from a particular Lambda invocation. (It is not sufficient to simply filter by log stream, as a single log stream can contain logs from multiple invocations if the invocations were run within the same environment, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491906/multiple-triggered-aws-lambda-logs-are-displayed-in-a-single-cloudwatch-log-stre/58494572#58494572).)

Unfortunately, when a Python AWS Lambda function crashes due to an unhandled exception, the log record for the exception does **not** include the request ID. The obvious solution is to log unhandled exceptions via the `logging` module, so that request ID is included in the log record. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16993115/8763290) appears to be the cleanest solution but it does not work in this case because overriding `sys.excepthook` does not appear to have any effect within a Lambda environment ([here](https://github.com/gkrizek/leh#readme) is the only other source I can find that references this fact).

Therefore, I'm wondering if there's a recommended way to include request ID in the log record for an unhandled exception in a Python AWS Lambda function? This seems like a problem that should have a standard solution. Otherwise, I will just surround the lambda handler code with a `try`/`except` to log and re-raise all unhandled exceptions.

Comment: You have to just use try/except and log it yourself.

Comment: Fully with you on "This seems like a problem that should have a standard solution".

I'm looking for a slightly enhanced experience, to go quickly from error peaks in a CloudWatch metric to the corresponding lambda's unhandled exception logs... It isn't looking very promising. I can't even find a quick way to jump to the unhandled exceptions by poor man's time range filtering + text filtering...

Comment: @UldisBarbans [Here](https://github.com/ASFHyP3/hyp3/blob/v3.9.7/lib/lambda_logging/lambda_logging/__init__.py) is what we came up with. Use like [this](https://github.com/ASFHyP3/hyp3/blob/v3.9.7/apps/start-execution-worker/src/start_execution_worker.py#L36-L41).